# No server response for AJAX request when accessing site via Google Translate

Tags: javascript, php, cors, google-translate

I've hit a snag with my site when it is run through Google Translate: my server does not respond at all to my browser for an AJAX request, not a single header.

The request URL looks like:

https://translate.google.com/translate?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&tl=sq&u=https://www.example.com/

Google Translate sends an `origin` request header with the value `https://translate.googleusercontent.com`.

I've made numerous attempts, here are essentially the header responses I've attempted to setup via PHP:

1. `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://translate.googleusercontent.com');`
2. `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`
3. `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');`
4. `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: translate.googleusercontent.com');`
5. `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: googleusercontent.com');`
6. `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: google.com');`

Obviously the `*` value is least secure but *nothing* working calls for more drastic experimentation. I also (without success) added this to the AJAX request:

```
//This is now removed due to research revealing this is why Chrome was making the request as 
//an HTTP OPTIONS method.
if (window.location.host!=domain) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');}
```

I've set PHP to email me a dump of `$_SERVER` via Google Translate requests:

```
Array
(
 [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
 [HTTPS] => on
 [HTTP_ACCEPT] => *
 [HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => utf-8,*
 [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,br
 [HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-alive
 [HTTP_HOST] => www.example.com
 [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => ***
 [HTTP_VIA] => 1.0 translate.google.com TWSFE/0.9
 [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => [my IP], [my IP...again]
 [PATH] => /bin:***
 [PHPRC] => ***
 [QUERY_STRING] => query=index.php
 [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
 [REMOTE_ADDR] => 66.102.8.203 [Google Proxy]
 [REMOTE_PORT] => ***
 [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
 [REQUEST_URI] => /
 [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => index.php
 [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
 [SERVER_ADDR] => ***
 [SERVER_ADMIN] => ***
 [SERVER_NAME] => www.example.com
 [SERVER_PORT] => 443
 [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
 [SERVER_SIGNATURE] =>
 [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
 [SSL_TLS_SNI] => www.example.com
 [UNIQUE_ID] => ***
 [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
 [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => ***
 [REQUEST_TIME] => ***
)
```

---

Firefox makes the request correctly using the HTTP `POST` method. For some reason Chrome makes the AJAX request using the HTTP `OPTION` method...wait what? That isn't how my site is coded.

I suspect that the server may be responding to Google's initial request server instead of my browser though I'm not sure. The `$_SERVER` *does* include a `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` with my IP address listed twice though I'm not sure how all that works out. I'm guessing this is a bit more complicated than a normal CORS request. How can I get my server to respond to my browser?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: @JamesMorrison Unfortunately this question is over four years old and while I really try to make sure I answer tough questions (because other people throw generic "answers" wasting our time) I likely got pulled away by demands on my time so I apologize that you found one of my questions sans an answer. I did just test this (using the domain from my profile) and it does work. My best off-hand recommendation is to try to use `die('here,1');` and have that go up in to the code until you get *-a-* response. Just think of your code like a conveyor-belt, eventually you'll find the issue. ︀ GL!